# Reading lines after a space

Tags: c, file-read

I have been trying to read the lines of a file. I only want what is after a space. This is the code I have:

```
void readFile()
{
  char line[256];                                       /* linia */
  int line_num = 0;                                 /* numero de linia */
  char resultat[4][256];    /* nom i valor del parametre els iguals els ignorem*/
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  int x=0;
  FILE * f;
  f = fopen(file_to_read, "r");
  if (f==NULL) { fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1); }
  while(fgets(line, 256, f) != NULL) {
    for (i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        if (line[i]==' ')
        {
            j=0;
            for (x=i+1; x<256 && line[x] != '\n';x++)
            {
                resultat[line_num][j]=line[x];
                j++;
            }
          resultat[line_num][j] = '\0';
            line_num++;
        }
    }
}

fclose(f);
```

Then I save the data in a struct and print it.

The code works most of the times but sometimes I get the segmentation fault error. I'm trying it with this text.

> Nom SW-01
>
> MAC 89F107457A36
>
> Server localhost
>
> Server-port 2019

What can be the problem?

Comment: change `for (i=0;i<256;i++)` to `for (i=0;line[i];i++)`

Comment: maybe `line_num` is getting greater than 3? Because the first dimension of the `resultat` array has only a dimension of 4. You could debug it or at least print the `line_num` out to stdout.

Comment: I think your loop seeks a buffer position that has no value and this is because you're assuming the file has lines up to 256 bytes, thats dangerours. I recommend you reading with read() method or make sure the lines has that length.

Comment: Please properly indent the code you post here.

Comment: Changing the condition on the for (line[i]) solved the problem. Thanks! Sorry about the indentation, I had it correctly but when I pasted it I didn't realized that wasn't indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

In the nested loop you have fetched all the characters after the space till you reach the \n. But when the process is over you come back to the first loop and the value of i hasn't been changed and it continues from the next character after the space again and that might exist another space in the line so you will repeat the line several times for each space in the line!

Therefore because of the `char resultat[4][256]` you might reach the limit and exceeds the boundary of the array.

You can update the i value after finishing the line `i=x`:

```
for (i=0;i<256;i++)
{
    if (line[i]==' ')
    {
        j=0;
        for (x=i+1; x<256 && line[x] != '\n';x++)
        {
            resultat[line_num][j]=line[x];
            j++;
        }
        resultat[line_num][j] = '\0';
        line_num++;
        i=x;
    }
}
```

BTW, actually I didn't like your code at all! And my suggestion is just a patch to fix your code, but there is definitely a much better way to write a code for what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry not very used to code in C, it was the first thing that came to me.

Comment: Nope sorry the problem was in the first for